# What's a good example of an basic back end index.js that's using express?

Tags: express, mean-stack

This is what I'm using and just wanted opinions. Been working on some teachable examples as way to also sharpen my skills, so input will go a long way.

```
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var api = require('./api');
var routing = require('./middleware/routing.mw');

var clientPath = path.join(__dirname, '../client');

var app = express();
app.use(express.static(clientPath));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use('/api', api);

app.get('*', routing.stateRouting);
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Take a look at the [express-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-generator).

Comment: Requests for an off-site resource (such as a pointer to an sample/example project) are #4 in the "some questions are still off-topic" list at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic